# Stop/Close webcam stream which is opened by navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc, getusermedia

I opened a webcam by using the following JavaScript code:

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ /* ... */ });
```

Is there any JavaScript code to stop or close the webcam?

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Since this answer has been originally posted the browser API has changed.
`.stop()` is no longer available on the stream that gets passed to the callback.
The developer will have to access the tracks that make up the stream (audio or video) and stop each of them individually.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/mediastream-deprecations?hl=en#stop-ended-and-active

Example (from the link above):

```js
stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
  track.stop();
});
```

Browser support may differ.

Previously, `navigator.getUserMedia` provided you with a stream in the success callback, you could call `.stop()` on that stream to stop the recording (at least in Chrome, seems FF doesn't like it)

Comment: I think `stream.stop()` doen't work for chrome, `mediaRecorder.stop()` stops the recording , whereas it doesn't stop the stream provided by browser. Can you look on to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715357/how-to-stop-the-capturing-mediastream-that-is-started-by-chrome-tabcapture-api-i

Comment: @Muntu, I think it depends, for me stream.stop() is working (in chrome). Because I have a webRTC stream. So if you are recording in browser mediaRecorder.stop() will work?

Comment: yes, but this raises another issue. This function to stop recording should occur after allowing a few seconds/minutes of recording. How can you control this: to stop it after a default time of recording? Thank you!

Comment: This stops the streams but the video indicator on chrome still remains active untill reload. Is there a way to remove that too?

Comment: @Cybersupernova Did you find a solution for this? I think page refresh might work

Comment: @samayo no i didn't found any and i cannot reload the page

Comment: @Muthu - The latest example on this answer seems to individually call track.stop() on all available tracks. When I use andrei's new code, the recording seems to "stop" and the stream gets fed all zeros but the success handler that was registered when I called getUserMedia won't stop running. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 119):

Use any of these functions:

```
// stop both mic and camera
function stopBothVideoAndAudio(stream) {
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        if (track.readyState == 'live') {
            track.stop();
        }
    });
}

// stop only camera
function stopVideoOnly(stream) {
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        if (track.readyState == 'live' && track.kind === 'video') {
            track.stop();
        }
    });
}

// stop only mic
function stopAudioOnly(stream) {
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        if (track.readyState == 'live' && track.kind === 'audio') {
            track.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. mediaStream.stop is being deprecated.

Comment: @DanBrown what is your solution?

Comment: I would strongly discourage modifying the prototype of a native API to _restore_ a feature that has been officially deprecated and removed from the browser. It's irregular and likely to cause confusion later. When you need to stop all the tracks in a stream, why not just do `stream.getTracks().forEach(track => { track.stop() })`? Or if you're really doing this often enough to justify a shorthand, you can always define a helper function like `stopAllTracks(stream)`.

Answer (score 62):

Don't use `stream.stop()`, it's deprecated

[MediaStream Deprecations](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/mediastream-deprecations?hl=en#stop-ended-and-active)

Use `stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())`

Comment: Thank you so much,, it's working totally fine, due to the depreciation it's confusing people that which one is working but as of march-2019 the above solution is working fine in chrome.. 

Comment: How to resume the track ?

Comment: @NeerajJain https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#mediastreamtrack

Comment: @NeerajJain once you close a mediaStreamTrack it can not exit the ended state

Comment: Not working on iOS devices. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 24):

FF, Chrome and Opera has started exposing `getUserMedia` via `navigator.mediaDevices` as standard now (Might change :)

[online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sasivarunan/2xLbv7n9/)

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true,video:true})
    .then(stream => {
        window.localStream = stream;
    })
    .catch( (err) =>{
        console.log(err);
    });
// later you can do below
// stop both video and audio
localStream.getTracks().forEach( (track) => {
track.stop();
});
// stop only audio
localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
// stop only video
localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

Answer (score 20):

Suppose we have streaming in video tag and id is video  - `<video id="video"></video>` then we should have following code -

```
var videoEl = document.getElementById('video');
// now get the steam 
stream = videoEl.srcObject;
// now get all tracks
tracks = stream.getTracks();
// now close each track by having forEach loop
tracks.forEach(function(track) {
   // stopping every track
   track.stop();
});
// assign null to srcObject of video
videoEl.srcObject = null;
```

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for! Thanks! This use case should be the most popular.

Answer (score 10):

Starting Webcam Video with different browsers

For Opera 12

```
window.navigator.getUserMedia(param, function(stream) {
                            video.src =window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                        }, videoError );
```

For Firefox Nightly 18.0

```
window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia(param, function(stream) {
                            video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                        }, videoError );
```

For Chrome 22

```
window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(param, function(stream) {
                            video.src =window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                        },  videoError );
```

Stopping Webcam Video with different browsers

For Opera 12

```
video.pause();
video.src=null;
```

For Firefox Nightly 18.0

```
video.pause();
video.mozSrcObject=null;
```

For Chrome 22

```
video.pause();
video.src="";
```

With this the Webcam light go down everytime...

Comment: This only stops showing the video in the <video> tag, but doesn't stop the camera.

Answer (score 8):

Try method below:

```
var mediaStream = null;
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {
            audio: true,
            video: true
        },
        function (stream) {
            mediaStream = stream;
            mediaStream.stop = function () {
                this.getAudioTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
                this.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) { //in case... :)
                    track.stop();
                });
            };
            /*
             * Rest of your code.....
             * */
        });

    /*
    * somewhere insdie your code you call
    * */
    mediaStream.stop();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can end the stream directly using the stream object returned in the success handler to getUserMedia. e.g.

```
localMediaStream.stop()
```

`video.src=""` or `null` would just remove the source from video tag. It wont release the hardware.

Comment: Not really... On firefox does not work. The docs mention that this method is not implemented in all browsers...

Comment: The above solution did not work for me. This did it.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need the tracks to close the streaming, and you need the `stream` boject to get to the tracks, the code I have used with the help of the Muaz Khan's answer above is as follows:

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) {
        videoEl.src = stream;
        videoEl.play();
        document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', function () {
            stopStream(stream);
        });
    }, errBack);

function stopStream(stream) {
console.log('stop called');
stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) {
    track.stop();
});
```

Of course this will close all the active video tracks. If you have multiple, you should select accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

If the `.stop()` is deprecated then I don't think we should re-add it like @MuazKhan dose. It's a reason as to why things get deprecated and should not be used anymore. Just create a helper function instead... Here is a more es6 version

```
function stopStream (stream) {
    for (let track of stream.getTracks()) { 
        track.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (let track of stream.getTracks()) {

                track.stop()
            }`

Comment: `stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) { track.stop() })` in ES5, this avoids [lengthy babel transforms of `for of`](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=for%20(let%20track%20of%20stream.getTracks())%20%7B%20track.stop()%20%7D)

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop all tracks (from webcam, microphone):

```
localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
```

Answer (score 2):

### Start and Stop Web Camera,(Update 2020  React es6 )

**Start Web Camera**

```
stopWebCamera =()=>

       //Start Web Came
      if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        //use WebCam
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
          this.localStream = stream;
          this.video.srcObject = stream;
          this.video.play();
        });
      }
 }
```

**Stop Web Camera or Video playback in general**

```
stopVideo =()=>
{
        this.video.pause();
        this.video.src = "";
        this.video.srcObject = null;

         // As per new API stop all streams
        if (this.localStream)
          this.localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
}
```

**Stop Web Camera function works even with video streams:**

```
  this.video.src = this.state.videoToTest;
  this.video.play();
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop and then re-start a screen capture share without making the user choose the window again?

Answer (score 0):

Using .stop() on the stream works on chrome when connected via http. It does not work when using ssl (https).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/wazb1jks/3/

```js
navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints, function(stream) {
    window.streamReference = stream;
}, onMediaError);
```

Stop Recording

```js
function stopStream() {
    if (!window.streamReference) return;

    window.streamReference.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        track.stop();
    });

    window.streamReference.getVideoTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        track.stop();
    });

    window.streamReference = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
public vidOff() {

      let stream = this.video.nativeElement.srcObject;
      let tracks = stream.getTracks();

      tracks.forEach(function (track) {
          track.stop();
      });

      this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = null;
      this.video.nativeElement.stop();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, but it worked only intermittently. It was not until I close the component in React that the camera light disappears. I would suggest create your component where you hide/show the component, in order to remove the camera completely.

```
    const stream = document.querySelector("video").srcObject;
    console.log("videoElement", stream, stream.active);

    stream?.getVideoTracks()?.forEach((track) => {
      console.log("track 1", track);
      track.stop();
      stream?.removeTrack(track);
      track = null;
      console.log("track 2", track);
    });
    stream?.getTracks()?.forEach((track) => {
      console.log("track 3", track);
      track.stop();
      stream?.removeTrack(track);
      track = null;
      console.log("track 4", track);
    });
    stream?.getAudioTracks()?.forEach((track) => {
      console.log("track 5", track);
      track.stop();
      stream?.removeTrack(track);
      track = null;
      console.log("track 6", track);
    });
    console.log("videoElement 2", stream, stream.active);
    stream = null;

    const videoElem = document.querySelector("video");
    if (videoElem) {
      console.log("element exists", videoElem);
      videoElem.pause();
      videoElem.removeAttribute("src");
      videoElem.src = "";
      videoElem.remove();
      console.log("element exists 2", videoElem);
    }
```

[image: camera still on after trying everything...]

Because the above didn't close the camera completely, I would suggest you would have your component

```
const [isCameraOn, setCameraOn] = useState(false)
```

set your video component like this

```
{isCameraOn && (<YourVideoComponent/>)}
```

Comment: I tried this for an audio component, but even if the component is not rendered, the microphone is still open and listening. The only way to stop is to refresh the page. I'm sure this is possible to stop, because tools like Google Meet does so without any refresh. Maybe it's just a bug in the implementation of `navigator.mediaDevices`?

Comment: same, I also had to do a refresh. the only thing I could think of is that this is happening because of different libraries being used in my code, and there's a conflict somewhere in code.

Comment: Hey, I couldn't update you yesterday, but I figured out the solution. It's because we didn't close the correct resource properly. I think you already know this, since you say "It was not until I close the component in React that the camera light disappears.". You just have to make sure the correct stream is closed when the component unmounts (or in response to something else like user clicking "turn off" or "mute"). Initially it didn't work because I was creating a new stream and closing that instead of the original stream. Now I put the original stream in a Ref (`useRef` hook) and close that.

Answer (score -3):

Have a reference of stream form successHandle

```
var streamRef;

var handleVideo = function (stream) {
    streamRef = stream;
}

//this will stop video and audio both track
streamRef.getTracks().map(function (val) {
    val.stop();
});
```

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as several others that have been already given.

Comment: Not by a long shot @DanDascalescu. See, in this example he clearly demonstrates his ability to recall the map function.

Comment: `.map` is inappropriate here. Use `forEach` if you aren't building an array.