# HTML5 localMediaStream stop function not releasing the webcam/hardware

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

I have implemented the head tracking feature using HTML5 `getUserMedia` using the [headtrackr](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/) library. Also, I have a canvas where I am drawing a smiley which moves on the movement of head while the webcam is tracking it.

So far so good. Things are working fine. The problem which I am facing is to stop the webcam.
I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642926/stop-close-webcam-which-is-opened-by-navigator-getusermedia) but nothing worked.

I understand that I have to stop the stream anyhow. I have a stop button which will not only stop the camera but also needs to clear the canvas. That is where the actual problem is. My stop function implementation is not releasing the webcam i.e it remains ON but headtracking stops and canvas is also not cleared.

Below is my javascript code

```
var cameraStream = null;
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
    || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var videoInput = document.getElementById('inputVideo');

if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
        fallback();
} else {
        navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio : true,
    video : true
   }, success, fallback);
 }

  document.addEventListener('facetrackingEvent', function(event) {
     $('#parameters').html(
                "Height: " + event.height + " Width: " + event.width + "\n     X: "
                    + event.x + " Y: " + event.y);
    setTimeout(function() {
            drawCircle(event.x, event.y);
       }, 500);
   });

  function fallback(e) {
     videoInput.src = 'fallbackvideo.webm';
     console.log('Reeeejected!', e);
  }   

  function success(stream) {
    alert(stream);
    cameraStream = stream;
    var canvasInput = document.getElementById('inputCanvas');
    videoInput.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

    var htracker = new headtrackr.Tracker();
    htracker.init(videoInput, canvasInput);
    htracker.start();
   }

  function drawCircle(x, y) {
   canvas = document.getElementById('faceCanvas');
   context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   context.strokeStyle = '#0000FF';
        context.fillStyle = '#FFFF00';
   context.lineWidth = 4;
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(x, y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
   context.closePath();
   context.stroke();
   context.fill();

    // The smile
    context.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y - 10, 40, 0.2 * Math.PI, 0.8 * Math.PI, false);
    // context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    // context.fill();

    // The Left eye
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x - 20, y - 15, 10, 0 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();

    // The Right Eye
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x + 20, y - 15, 10, 0 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
}

/**
 * stops head tracking
 */
function stopTracking(){
        cameraStream.stop();
        videoInput.src="";
      canvas  = document.getElementById('faceCanvas');
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  }
```

And my HTML code goes here

```
<canvas id="inputCanvas" ></canvas>
    <video id="inputVideo" autoplay=""></video>
    <div id="parameters"></div>
    <canvas id="faceCanvas"></canvas>
    <button id="stop" onclick="stopTracking();">Stop Tracking</button>
    <script src="resources/js/facedetection.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/headtrackr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

These steps, in this order, work for me.

1) Set `videoInput.src = ''`.

2) Make sure `cameraStream.stop` exists before calling it as a function. Firefox doesn't have it, and if you try to run it, your code will throw an error, and it will not stop the camera or clear the canvas.

3) After you call `cameraStream.stop()` (or not), set `cameraStream = null`.

Comment: didn't work when i follow this

`videoInput.src="";
 canvas = document.getElementById('faceCanvas');
 context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 cameraStream.stop();
 cameraStream = null;`

in order.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome, Canary and Firefox. http://jsbin.com/emitur/1 Also, for me, Chrome is buggy when it comes to releasing the camera. I often find I have to restart the browser to even get camera access after using it a few times.

Comment: No. Still not working. Hardware is not getting released in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`cameraStream.getVideoStreams()[0].stop()` - that worked for me, you may need to do the same with `getAudioStreams` if you have audio too.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this question is too old, I still want to leave a message to mind other guys who search this question, that is

> MediaStream.stop() is deprecated and will soon be removed. Use MediaStreamTrack.stop() instead.

If you work with Google Chrome >  45, please read [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/mediastream-deprecations?hl=en), it will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

cameraStream.stop() API is using a deprecated.
Change

```
   function stopTracking(){
        cameraStream.stop();
        videoInput.src="";
        canvas  = document.getElementById('faceCanvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
```

to

```
    function stopTracking(){
          cameraStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
          videoInput.src="";
          canvas  = document.getElementById('faceCanvas');
          context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your stop function not listening, I have checked here, please check with this by changing stop function with

```
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stopTracking);
```

then your stopTracking function with

```
function stopTracking(){
    if (videoInput.src) {
            cameraStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
            if( cameraStream.getVideoTracks().length > 0){
                cameraStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
                videoInput.src = null;
            }
        }
  canvas  = document.getElementById('faceCanvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

}

you need to loop through all available local streams.