# MediastreamTrack Stop - Webcam light on - HTTPS

Tags: html, jquery-webcam-plugin, webcam.js, mediastream

Can anyone please help with the fix for https . I am able to stop the video streaming using stop() but the camera light is still on . Was not able to find any fix in the other posts

```
mediaStream.stop();
// or
mediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

Comment: How is this related to https?

Comment: Thanks for replying .Seen couple of posts http://stackoverflow.com/a/15924000 which says the stop doesn't work with https . So guessed so . Do you have a fix for the issue? I am able to delete the video , but not get the webcam light stop

Answer (score -2):

Stream.stop deprecated.

```
 mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
```