# STOP Webcam after call hangup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webrtc, mod-verto

How to stop webcam (Close connection with camera) using `getUserMedia` in **webRTC**?

I tried with : `localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();`

But it will not work for me in chrome. connection with the camera continues as it is.

My **code** is

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || 
 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||  
 navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

if(navigator.getUserMedia){
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream) {
    localStream = stream;
    document.querySelector('#vidDisplay').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
};

function videoError(e)
{
    alert("There is some problem..");
};
```

Comment: Duplicate Question, solution in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642926/stop-close-webcam-which-is-opened-by-navigator-getusermedia

Comment: I tried using it @karthik but browser tab continues using the camera and black screen appears on view part.