# Closing webcam without reloading

Tags: reactjs, webcam, mediadevices

I'm a a beginner in web development and I’m working on a video chat app built with `create-react-app`. I’m using `recordRTC` library for record and stream from users’s webcam and microphone.
When I stop recording, I also would like to close the webcam.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RecordRTC from "recordrtc";

const captureUserMedia = callback => {
  const params = { audio: true, video: true };
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(params)
    .then(callback)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
};

export default class Recorder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.recordVideo = null;
    this.videoRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    captureUserMedia(stream => (this.videoRef.current.srcObject = stream));
  };

  startRecord = () => {
    captureUserMedia(stream => {
      this.recordVideo = RecordRTC(stream, { type: "video" });
      this.recordVideo.startRecording();
    });
  };

  stopRecord = () => {
    this.recordVideo.stopRecording();
    this.videoRef.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      track.stop();
    });
  };
    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <video ref={this.videoRef} autoPlay muted />
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.startRecord}>START</button>
          <button onClick={this.stopRecord}>STOP</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642926/stop-close-webcam-which-is-opened-by-navigator-getusermedia) a related post where I found this:

```
stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    track.stop()
})
```

This stop the stream but the red circle is still present on the navigator tab (chrome) and the webcam's light is still lightning.

How can I do to turn off the webcam ?

The only way i found is to force a reload but I don't really wanna do this ...

If someone have an idea, please let me know.

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Please add relevant code in the question instead of linking to it

Comment: Ok I did it... thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I found what I did wrong !

I called two times `getUserMedia()` method instead of one only  (with captureUserMedia function).

You can try with the code below it will be ok !!!

```
...

  componentDidMount = () => {
    captureUserMedia((stream) => {
      this.videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      this.recordVideo = RecordRTC(stream, { type: "video" });
    });
  };

  startRecord = () => {
      this.recordVideo.startRecording();
  };

  stopRecord = () => {
    this.recordVideo.stopRecording();
    this.videoRef.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      track.stop();
    });
  };

...
```