# Stop navigator.GetUserMedia camera access

Tags: javascript, html, camera, getusermedia

I have this camera app I'm making, and I have this camera code that starts a camera here it is.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
 // Get access to the camera
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
 });
}
```

The problem is, I am unable to stop it. So how do you stop it in javascript the navigator getUserMedia camera access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `stream.getTracks()` followed by `track.stop()`. For example:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
 // Get access to the camera
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
    setTimeout(() => {
      stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        if (track.readyState == 'live' && track.kind === 'video') {
          track.stop();
        }
      };
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

After 5 seconds, we stop the camera.

See: [Stop/Close webcam which is opened by navigator.getUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642926/stop-close-webcam-which-is-opened-by-navigator-getusermedia)